# How to detect where the function is called from in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code

```
var Test = function(){
    this.prefix = function(prefix, callback){
        callback.call({pre: prefix})
    }
    this.log = function(stuff){
        console.log(this.pre, stuff);
    }
}

var tester = new Test();
tester.log('a'); // should log 'a' -> logs undefined, 'a'

tester.prefix('b', function(){
    console.log(this.pre) // -> logs 'b'
    tester.log('c'); // should log 'bc' -> logs undefined, 'c'
})
tester.log('d'); // should log 'd' -> logs undefined, 'd'
```

Basically, when I'm running tester.log inside a prefix callback, it should log the output with a prefix before.
I know I can pass a new tester object with a predefined prefix in the callback function as a parameter. But can I do this without a parameter ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the question is. If `this.pre` is not defined, then of course `console.log(this.pre)` will log undefined. You also don't have any code that would *set* the value of `this.pre` anywhere.

Comment: console.log(this.pre) actually logs the value of this.pre, which is 'b' inside the prefix function, exactly like i wrote in the comments of my code. 
i'm trying to set this.pre with callback.call({pre: prefix}) which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set pre on the Test object:

```
var Test = function(){
    this.prefix = function(prefix, callback){
        this.pre = prefix;
        callback.call({pre: prefix})

    }
    this.log = function(stuff){
        console.log(this.pre, stuff);
    }
```

}

Comment: but after the first .prefix method, all logs after that will have that preffix, not just the ones inside the callback